# How to reject the same POST request sent twice in a short gap of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, api-gateway

I am wondering if there is a standard way to reject requests with the same body sent within a few seconds at the API gateway itself.

Forex: Reddit rejects if I try to post the same content within few seconds in a different group. Similarly, if I make a credit card payment for the second time, it automatically rejects it.

I am wondering if there is a way to have the same behavior in the **AWS API gateway** itself so that we are not handling it in lambda functions with dynamoDB and stuff.

Looking forward to efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: Unaware that this is a feature of any API gateway. Do you know those systems do it in an API gateway? Suspect it's their back-end de-duplicating POSTs.

Answer (score 2):

The API Gateway currently **doesn't** offer a feature like that, you'd have to implement this yourself.

If I was to implement this, I'd probably use an in-memory cache like ElastiCache for Redis or Memcached as the storage backend for deduplications.
For each incoming request I'd determine what makes it unique and create a hash from that.

Then I check if that hash value is in the cache already. If that's the case it 's a duplicate and I reject the request. If it isn't already in the cache, I'd add it with a time to live of `n` seconds (The time interval in which I wish to deduplicate).